# dup gives different results when hash is one vs. two dimensions

Tags: ruby, hash, shallow-copy, dup

`dup` is shallow copy, so when doing this:

```
h = {one: {a:'a', b: 'b'}}
h_copy = h.dup
h_copy[:one][:b] = 'new b'
```

now `h` and `h_copy` is same: `{:one=>{:a=>"a", :b=>"new b"}}`
yes, that right.

But when `h` is a one dimension hash:

```
h = {a:'a', b: 'b'}
h_copy = h.dup
h_copy[:b] = 'new b'
h still is: {a:'a', b: 'b'}
h_copy is {a:'a', b: 'new b'}
```

Why?

Comment: As you said, `dup` is shallow copy. What did you expect?

Comment: i want know why have different result,when hash one VS. two dimensions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So after 1 hour of brainstorming..I have come to the conclusion that in the multi dimensional hashes, the dup generates the same object_id for each key which is in turn referring to the hash whereas in the single dimensional hash, the object_ids are similar initially but when we make any changes to the object the Ruby would assign new object_id to the hash keys..

Look at the following code

```
h = { :a => "a", :b => "b" } # => {:a=>"a", :b=>"b"} 
h_clone = h.dup #=> {:a=>"a", :b=>"b"} 
h.object_id #=> 73436330 
h_clone.object_id #=> 73295920 
h[:a].object_id #=> 73436400 
h_clone[:a].object_id #=> 73436400 
h[:b].object_id #=> 73436380 
h_clone[:b].object_id #=> 73436380 
h_clone[:b] = "New B" #=> "New B" 
h_clone[:b].object_id #=> 74385280 
h.object_id #=> 73436330 
h_clone.object_id #=> 73295920 
h[:a].object_id #=> 73436400 
h_clone[:a].object_id #=> 73436400
```

Look the following code for the multidimensional array

```
h = { :one => { :a => "a", :b => "b" } } #=> {:one=>{:a=>"a", :b=>"b"}} 
h_copy = h.dup #=> {:one=>{:a=>"a", :b=>"b"}} 
h_copy.object_id #=> 80410620 
h.object_id #=> 80552610 
h[:one].object_id #=> 80552620 
h_copy[:one].object_id #=> 80552620 
h[:one][:a].object_id #=> 80552740 
h_copy[:one][:a].object_id #=> 80552740 
h[:one][:b].object_id #=> 80552700 
h_copy[:one][:b].object_id #=> 80552700 
h_copy[:one][:b] = "New B" #=> "New B" 
h_copy #=> {:one=>{:a=>"a", :b=>"New B"}} 
h #=> {:one=>{:a=>"a", :b=>"New B"}} 
h.object_id #=> 80552610 
h_copy.object_id #=> 80410620 
h[:one].object_id #=> 80552620 
h_copy[:one].object_id #=> 80552620 
h[:one][:b].object_id #=> 81558770 
h_copy[:one][:b].object_id #=> 81558770
```

Answer (score 3):

You can think about your two-dimensional hash as some kind of container, which conatins another hash container. So you have **2** containers.

When you call `dup` on `h`, then `dup` returns you copy of your outermost container, but any inner containers are not copied, so this is what shallow copy does. Now after dup you have **3** containers: `h_copy` is your new third container, which `:one` key just points to `h`'s inner container

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `dup` is shallow copy.

It appears you want both `h_copy` and `h` to refer to the same object.

Then simply do `h_copy = h` (i.e. no `dup`).

```
h = {a:'a', b: 'b'}
h_copy = h.dup
h_copy[:b] = 'new b'
h #=> {a:'a', b: 'new b'}
```

Comment: we can simply do this::
h = {a:'a', b: 'b'}
h_copy = h
h_copy[:b] = "new b"
h #{:a=>"a", :b=>"new b"}
h_copy #{:a=>"a", :b=>"new b"}